# Object arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If I do this,

```
var element = {};
alert(element);
element[name] = "stephen";
alert(element.name);
```

Why doesn't `element.name` work?

Answer (score 17):

When using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation), (unless it's a variable) it needs to be in qoutes, like this:

```
var element = {}; 
alert(element); 
element["name"] = "stephen"; 
alert(element.name);
```

[You cant test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Y9hdA/).  To explain what I mean by "unless it's a variable", this would also work:

```
var myVariable = "name";
element[myVariable] = "stephen";
```

Answer (score 8):

Because name should be in quotes.
This works:

```
var element = {};
alert(element);
element['name'] = "stephen";
alert(element.name);
```

[Try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/QtER2/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason why you may want to get an object's property dynamically. For example:

You have a variable, but you can't be sure of its value. The server send you the variable value so you should write like this.

```
obj[name].age // Here the name is a variable, and it can be changed in every page refresh, for example.
```

But if you want to set `obj['name'] = 'Lorenzo'` you have to use quotes.

Think like `obj[name]` is used for set, `obj['name']` is used for get.